# Adding black frame to an image using python

Tags: python, image, error-handling

I have a dataset with a couple of different sized images. To train my neural network I wanted to change the size of this images to one common size by adding a black frame around all my images. I used the following code:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 


old_im = Image.open('C:/Users/tobis/OneDrive/Desktop/Masterarbeit/data/2017-IWT4S-HDR_LP-dataset/crop_h1/I00002.png')
old_size = old_im.size
print(old_size)

new_size = (800, 800)
print(new_size)
new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)   ## luckily, this is already black!
new_im.paste(old_im, ((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2,
                      (new_size[1]-old_size[1])/2))
```

And got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-3363f60dba3b> in <module>
     11 new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)   ## luckily, this is already black!
     12 new_im.paste(old_im, ((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2,
---> 13                       (new_size[1]-old_size[1])/2))

~\.conda\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in paste(self, im, box, mask)
   1466             self.im.paste(im, box, mask.im)
   1467         else:
-> 1468             self.im.paste(im, box)
   1469 
   1470     def alpha_composite(self, im, dest=(0, 0), source=(0, 0)):

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

I do not know why I got this error. I checked the types of my variable entries and they are all integers and there are no floats... I am also surprised that the first substraction seems to be okay and the second one rises an issue...

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division is producing a floating point number but the method requires integers.

```
new_size = (800, 800)
print(new_size)
new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)   ## luckily, this is already black!
x = int((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2)
y = int((new_size[1]-old_size[1])/2))
new_im.paste(old_im, (x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!